# Is there an Xcode syntax colouring for Rails, Ruby, Erb? If not, how can I write one myself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, syntax

Xcode's syntax colouring is poor at best and textmate's looks great, but I like Xcode, since I program in C++, too.  I'd like to keep everything in one place and take advantage of other Xcode features.

Has anyone already done this or is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Omar's response, below, appears to answer this question. Why not mark it as answered?

Answer (score 7):

You can go to Editor>Syntax Coloring>Check HTML and do it again for Ruby

Answer (score 3):

After some googling, it looks like there **is** indeed some support for ERB files in XCode. It's a little hidden, though.

Check this page out: [ERB Highlighting](http://wotnau.blogspot.com/2009/03/xcode-erb-file-highlighting.html). In brief, XCode is looking for .rhtml files instead of .erb files, so .erb files don't trigger the ERB syntax highlighting. The solution, then, is to go open

> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Standard file types.pbfilespec

look for the mapping for rhtml:

> Extensions = (shtml, jsp, rhtml);

And add erb to the list:

> Extensions = (shtml, jsp, rhtml, erb);

Viola! Just restart XCode and you'll get erb syntax highlighting. There's probably a way to do it from within XCode itself, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: This isn't necessary anymore. You can go to Editor>Syntax Coloring>Check HTML and do it again for Ruby.

Comment: Thanks @HamedSaadat. You should add your comment as an answer for more visibility. It took me a while before I noticed it.

Comment: Okay just posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode can do custom syntax coloring, you need two files

- `pbfilespec`: specifies MIME type, extension and some meta info
- `xclangspec`: which holds identifiers etc. that need colouring

and put them somewhere in `~/Library/Application Support/..`

I'm a Textmate user myself, so don't know if such a thing exists for ruby, and neither a more exact specification for those files, but examples for other languages can easily be found.

Comment: Xcode does have native syntax highlighting for Ruby, though it isn't as thorough as it is for C, Java or JavaScript. TextMate seems to have the best coverage of all.